# Error while watching folder and file for change

Tags: node.js, daemon, fs, file-watcher

I am tailing a file for change and using fs.watch on a directory for newly added files and I received the following error causing my app to crash after a couple of hours working?

Any ideas what this means or why it would occur?

```js
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ECONNRESET: connection reset by peer, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:133:12) {
  errno: -4077,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  filename: null
```

Comment: Is the directory you're watching on a network drive/mount?

Comment: (Also, you might want to look at https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar for a better watch experience.)

Comment: It is on a network drive, would you say I lost connection to that drive? Looked into chokidar but had issues watching a network folder.

Comment: I would say you intermittently lost network connection, yeah.